# Show Visual Studio Online option

Tags: azure-functions, azureportal

I used to have Visual Studio Online option under Development Tools section where I can enable or disable Visual Studio. But that option is no longer there. How do I add that option back in the list? I just want to upload project.json file so that I can include external assemblies. This is the page I'm using as a reference : [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference/#fileupdate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it's no longer Visual Studio Online. It's called App Service Editor.